# Reload main view after modal dismiss

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

In my Xcode-App, a modal can be opened from every view. Every *'base'* view is having a different purpose, some are showing a table, some are doing not. How can I achieve to reload the *'base'* view whenever the modal is dismissed?

It seems to be especially tricky as the views have such different structures and purposes. I tried `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear` and `viewDidLoad`, but none of them seem to do the trick.

Comment: willAppear and DidAppear should be called ...

Comment: They are not. I tried to figure out by `print("dismissed")` in the base VCs, but nothing happens. I dismiss the modal by `override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {}` by the way.

Comment: viewWillAppear is not called with iOS 13 modals (they are not full screen), but you can setup a delegate system between your modal and the presenting view to notify when the modal will or did disappear.

Comment: How will I do this exactly, @rraphael ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup a delegate pattern so that your modal view can notify when it will or did disappear.

First you need to create a protocol for your delegate:

```swift
protocol ModalViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func modalControllerWillDisapear(_ modal: ModalViewController)
}
```

Then your modal should have a delegate property (that will in the end be the presenting controller) and trigger the `modalControllerWillDisapear` method when needed:

```swift
final class ModalViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: ModalViewControllerDelegate?

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        delegate?.modalControllerWillDisapear(self)
    }
}
```

And all view controller that will present your modal controller must conform to that protocol and assign itself as a delegate of the modal when presenting:

```swift
final class SomeViewController: UIViewController {
    private func presentModalController() {
        let modal = ModalViewController()
        modal.delegate = self
        self.present(modal, animated: true)
    }
}

extension SomeViewController: ModalViewControllerDelegate {
    func modalControllerWillDisapear(_ modal: ModalViewController) {
        // This is called when your modal will disappear. You can reload your data.
        print("reload")
    }
}
```

**Note:** If you are using segues to present your modal, you can assign the delegate property in the `prepare(for:sender:)` method instead of in a custom method.

```swift
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    switch (segue.identifier, segue.destination) {
        // Check that the segue identifer matches and destination controller is a ModalViewController
    case ("showModalSegue", let destination as ModalViewController):
        destination.delegate = self
    case _:
        break
    }
}
```